# How can I view current file only instead of all marked files in ranger?

Tags: linux, ranger

In the ranger file manager, https://github.com/ranger/ranger, how can I open the currently selected file instead of all marked files?

I'd like to iterate through a directory and choose whether I mark each file after viewing it. I cannot really think of a scenario where I'd like to open all marked files, so I'd be happy with a solution that changes the default behavior of `<Enter>` or `l`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to change the default because `l` and `<enter>` maps to `move right=1` but I use `O` (for open) instead:

```
map O shell -f open %f
```

(`%f` maps to the highlighted file)